# Diagonal transparent lines are added while converting UIView to UIImage

Tags: uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to convert UIView containing 2 UIImageView to UIImage. Almost everything is working fine, but on final conversion some transparent diagonal lines are shown in final UIImage. I cant understand why is this happening. If someone can help. Thanks.

```
extension UIView {
    /**
     Convert UIView to UIImage
     */
    func toImage() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.isOpaque, 0.0)
        self.drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
        let snapshotImageFromMyView = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return snapshotImageFromMyView!
    }
}
```

following are before and after saving image
enter image descript[image]Before Saving[image]After Saving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, my code was converting resulting UIImage to Webp at 0.70 quality. That was adding lines in image. By saving jpg and then converting to webp fixed the problem.